# JQuery posting files and text through ajax

Tags: jquery, django, image

I've got a Django webapp with a sort of newsfeed functionality. Newsfeeds have titles, bodies, and images associated with them. Users have the ability to edit and update their newsfeeds, including adding a new image.

Currently I'm getting all the data for each feed item like so:

```
var newsfeeds = [];
$('.feed').each( function (index, element) {
    var feed_dict = {'title': $(this).children('#title').val(),
                     'id': $(this).children('#feed_' + index + '_id').val(),
                     'should_delete': $(this).children('#should_delete').val(),
                     'subtitle': $(this).children('#subtitle').val(),
                     'body': $(this).children('#body').val()};
    newsfeeds.push(feed_dict);
});
```

It's then sent off using `$.ajax()`. This is working great.

Now I'm working on the image stuff. Each feed has an associated `<input type="/>` with a unique ID, so I should be able to get each file. The question then is how to send them off in such a way that I can get all the data in Django's `request.POST` and `request.FILES`. I've tried using a `FormData` object in JS like so:

```
var data = new FormData();
$('.image_input').each(function(index, element) {
    data.append('file_' + index, element.files);
});
```

But this gives me a `NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA` in Firebug.

At this point, I'm pretty lost. Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: is this a browser-specific issue?

Comment: I don't think so -- it doesn't work in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually impossible to send files over ajax - if you use something like the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to 'hijack' your form, it will submit it to an iframe behind the scenes instead of using XHR.

In any case, you should really write your forms in such a way that they work without javascript, then use jquery form to [progressively enhance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) them. Then you won't even need to worry about this sort of thing.

Comment: Really? It's not possible at all? What's the difference, then, between an XHR request and a normal POST from the browser?

Comment: XHR is created via javascript, a normal POST comes from submitting a form... I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. But in any case, yes, it is impossible.

Note that I'm not saying you can't submit files over ajax at all, it's just that behind the scenes you need to use a hidden iframe to do it.

Comment: Well, I rewrote the code to use a form and it works perfectly. Thanks!